# How to limit samples in 100 Chartjs

Tags: javascript, charts

I'm in a project that need show only the last 100 samples on chart.js. For now, I have this:

[image]

I'm using node and mongo, my query gives the last 100 already. If I have 100 samples, it will reflect on chartjs?

Code:

```
var lineChartData = {
      labels: parsedTime,
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Umidade",
          data: parsedHumidity,
          backgroundColor: [
            "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
            "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)",
            "rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)",
            "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)",
            "rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)",
            "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)"
          ],
          borderColor: [
            "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
            "rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)",
            "rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)",
            "rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)",
            "rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)",
            "rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)"
          ],
          borderWidth: 1
        }
      ],
      options: {
        scales: {
          yAxes: [
            {
              ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    };
```

Besides that, the API receives samples every 30 seconds. How can i show only the last 100 samples in real time?

Thank you guys

Comment: what is the question than ?

Comment: Can you give us sample data and possibly snippet?

Comment: Yes, what is the problem ?

Comment: To clarify my question (I will edit), the API receives samples every 30 seconds. I need only the last 100 samples in 'real time'. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chartjs provides the ability to add and remove data on the fly.

```
function addData(chart, label, data) {
    chart.data.labels.push(label);
    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        dataset.data.push(data);
    });
    chart.update();
}

function removeData(chart) {
    chart.data.labels.pop();
    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        dataset.data.pop();
    });
    chart.update();
}
```

Each time your api returns latest records, you will update your chart with the latest received data by using the above functions.
Reference: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html

Comment: Thank you. To do the update stuff, i used setTimeOut